# Reagent configuration for multi-page applications

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, reagent, figwheel, shadow-cljs

My `project.clj` has,

```
  :cljsbuild {:builds
              {:app
               {:source-paths ["src/cljs" "src/cljc"]
                :compiler {:output-to "target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js"
                           :output-dir "target/cljsbuild/public/js/out"
                           :main "my.core"
                           :asset-path "/js/out"
                           :optimizations :none
                           :source-map true
                           :pretty-print true}}}}
```

and I include `app.js` in my `list.html`, using [Selmer](https://github.com/yogthos/Selmer), like so,

```
{% block page-scripts %}
{% script "/js/app.js" %}
{% endblock %}
```

at the end of my `list.cljs`, I have

```
(r/render [list] (.getElementById js/document "content"))
```

so far so good.

Now, I would like to have another page, say `detail.cljs`, that I also like to render similarly,

```
(r/render [detail] (.getElementById js/document "content"))
```

The problem is, I just have a single `app.js` and including that in `detail.html` will render list content there too. Btw, I want one url for `list` page, and another for `detail`.

**Question:**

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClojureScript development for the past 2 years is much easier to do using the Deps/CLI facility along with Figwheel Main (a.k.a Figwheel 2.0) rather than the older Leiningen method.  Just look at the page [Create a Build](https://figwheel.org/docs/create_a_build.html) at `figwheel.org`, and then create multiple `*.cljs.edn` files such as:

```
some-page.cljs.edn
another-page.cljs.edn
...
```

Each of these can be as simple as:

```
{:main some-page.core}
```

and compile via:

```
clojure -m figwheel.main --build-once some-page
```

which will produce an output file

```
target/public/cljs-out/some-page-main.js
```

---

Be sure to see [Code Splitting](https://figwheel.org/docs/code_splitting.html) documentation for Figwheel, and [Code Splitting](https://clojurescript.org/guides/code-splitting) on `clojurescript.org`. Of course, ***be sure*** to go through all of the [Tutorial](https://figwheel.org/tutorial) and [Documentation](https://figwheel.org/docs/) from the start.  Enjoy!

For `shadow-cljs`, there is [Code Splitting ClojureScript](https://github.com/thheller/code-splitting-clojurescript) example app and a [blog entry](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2019/03/03/code-splitting-clojurescript.html).

---

Note: You could also look at the [Extra Mains](https://figwheel.org/docs/extra_mains.html) feature, but this is more limited.

Comment: If you make 2 completely independent builds the user will have to download all code again for each page. If the user is likely to visit many pages then it is much better to split the code using `:modules` and re-using the shared/cached code as that can substantially reduce the download size.

Answer (score 3):

Using shadow-cljs, you can specify several modules with different `init-fn`s in your build spec.

Your `shadow-cljs.edn` could contain something like this:

```
{:builds {:client {:target "browser"
                   :modules {:some-page {:init-fn org.example.foo/run}
                             :another-page {:init-fn org.example.bar/run
                                            :depends-on #{:some-page}}}}}}
```

The names of the `.js` files are determined from the module name, here `some-page.js` and `another-page.js`.

Comment: Ideally you would have a `:shared` module that both pages depend on. That way each page only gets exactly what is needed. If you make one page depend on another like the example then both `:init-fn` calls will execute when visiting `:another-page`.