# How to create a multi-page application with Figwheel and Leiningen?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

I have a [simple Figwheel](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel) application which is built with Leiningen.

I want to have multiple pages in it:

- [index.html](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel/blob/master/resources/public/index.html) should use the code from [hello-figwheel.core](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel/blob/master/src/hello_figwheel/core.cljs).
- [page2.html](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel/blob/master/resources/public/page2.html) should use the code from [hello-figwheel.page2](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel/blob/master/src/hello_figwheel/page2.cljs)

I assume I have to somehow modify the [project.clj](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel/blob/master/project.clj) file:

```
:compiler {:main hello-figwheel.core
           :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
           :output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/hello_figwheel.js"
           :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
           :source-map-timestamp true
           ;; To console.log CLJS data-structures make sure you enable devtools in Chrome
           ;; https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools
           :preloads [devtools.preload]}}
```

How can I tell Leiningen to compile

- `hello-figwheel.core` to `resources/public/js/compiled/hello_figwheel.js` and
- `hello-figwheel.page2` to `resources/public/js/compiled/page2.js`?

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257686/reagent-configuration-for-multi-page-applications). The difference to this one is that Leiningen is used to run Figwheel.

**Update 1:** I added the following to the [project.clj](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel/blame/master/project.clj) file:

```
{
                :id "page2"
                :source-paths ["src"]
                :compiler {
                           :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/page2"
                           :output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/page2/main.js"
                           :main hello-figwheel.page2
                           :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                           :source-map-timestamp true
                           ;; To console.log CLJS data-structures make sure you enable devtools in Chrome
                           ;; https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools
                           :preloads [devtools.preload]}

                :figwheel {:on-jsload "hello-figwheel.page2/on-js-reload"
                           ;; :open-urls will pop open your application
                           ;; in the default browser once Figwheel has
                           ;; started and compiled your application.
                           ;; Comment this out once it no longer serves you.
                           :open-urls ["http://localhost:3449/page2.html"]}
                }
```

When I run `lein figwheel`, the REPL is unable to connect to my web application:

[image: lein figwheel]

It says `Prompt will show when Figwheel connects to your application`, but it never happens.

Also, if I open `http://localhost:3449/page2.html` in the browser, update [page2.cljs](https://github.com/mentiflectax/hello-figwheel/blob/master/src/hello_figwheel/page2.cljs), and refresh the page in the browser, the changes are not visible there.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/master/README.md#multiple-build-configurations ?

Comment: @cfrick I tried -- see update 1.

Comment: I strongly suggest looking into [ShadowCLJS](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs) over Figwheel

Comment: @CalebMacdonaldBlack Can you tell me the single most important benefit of ShadowCLJS over Figwheel?

Comment: Dealing with npm dependencies is far easier in ShadowCLJS than in figwheel. Externs basically aren’t needed. 

IMO the configuration is simpler too.

Comment: Also amazing support from its creator Thomas Heller in the Clojure Slack channel